# How to change the language of strings like "read more" and "submitted by"?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've managed to create a website with Drupal 8.3.7.

How do I get Drupal to print things like "Read more" in views and "Submitted by", "Wednesday, August 23" in an article or `t("something supposedly translated")` in another language?

I'd like the administration interface to remain in English. I'd like to avoid a language prefix in URLs (yes: /mycurrenturlalias, no: /XX/mycurrenturlalias) but at this point I really don't even care anymore.

I've tried installing the Language module, adding a new language, setting it as the default and only language, installing some translation modules and fiddling with their settings. I've broken the site in some interesting ways but what I haven't gotten is a single translation of those strings anywhere. I must be doing something horribly wrong, but please ignore that and just tell me what should work.

Comment: Hard to say what you're doing wrong without seeing it. First, do you want to have a single language (but not EN)? Then it should be enough to add that language and make it the default and use the interface translation as mentioned in the answer. If multiple languages, you need a way to identify the language, so that would be a url prefix or different domains. if the answer doesn't work, please provide a list of the modules and the screenshots of the relevant pages mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the core modules Language and Interface Translation
2. Add other language (admin/config/regional/language)
3. Configure the Selected language setting (admin/config/regional/language/detection)
4. To have a different language in admin enable the detection method ***Account administration pages***
5. Go to user/1/edit and in *Language settings* section select your *Administration pages language*
6. Translate your strings (admin/config/regional/translate)

Comment: This also affected the admin interface. After navigating a foreign language and trying random things for way too long I got the admin stuff in english and content for visitors in the desired language but now url aliases stopped working and the admin interface language occasionally changes.

Comment: @user3450244 I updated my answer.